# Finding different eigenvectors

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

When I'm in a hurry (such as on an exam), I let MATLAB or my TI-89 compute eigenvectors from a square matrix. This is all good and well, except for the times I want to use the eigenvectors for forming a modal matrix to do diagonalization. Sometimes, the eigenvectors that are returned from the tools form a modal matrix that is not invertible, and I end up spending a good chunk of time finding new eigenvectors that work out by hand.

Are there any kind of shortcuts or tricks I can do to the non-invertible modal matrix to quickly come up with a new one (that may be invertible)?

Comment: This would be much easier to answer if you could give us a sample input and output.  It's clear that the problem is diagonalizability, so what does matlab do with, for example,
$$
\pmatrix{4&0&0&0\\0&3&1&0\\0&0&3&0\\0&0&0&3}?
$$

Comment: I'll give you an example, but I am looking for generic approaches since I don't know what will be on the exam... If I have the matrix $A = \begin{bmatrix}
 -1 &  2 &  0 \\
 0 &  -1 &  0 \\
 0 &  0 &  -2
\end{bmatrix}$ and I type the matlab command [eigVc,eigVl]=eig(A);, I get the following result for eigVc: $eigVc = 
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 &  -1 &  0 \\
 0 &  0 &  0 \\
 0 &  0 &  1
\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: That matrix is not diagonalizable, so there cannot be three linearly independent eigenvectors.

Comment: @user2913869 for the eigenvalues, does it say something like $\{-1,-1,2\}$?

Comment: I found a modal matrix that was invertible that got me a Jordan Normal form: $M = 
\begin{bmatrix}
 0 &  1 &  0 \\
 0 &  0 &  0.5 \\
 1 &  0 &  0
\end{bmatrix}$  which resulted in $J = M^{-1}AM = 
\begin{bmatrix}
 -2 &  0 &  0 \\
 0 &  -1 &  1 \\
 0 &  0 &  -1
\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: yes Omnom, $eigVl = 
\begin{bmatrix}
 -1 &  0 &  0 \\
 0 &  -1 &  0 \\
 0 &  0 &  -2
\end{bmatrix}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What Matlab gives you is the set of eigenvalues (with algebraic multiplicity) and as many linearly independent eigenvectors as it can give you.

When $A$ is not diagonalizable, there will not be enough linearly independent eigenvectors.  In order to put the matrix into Jordan canonical form, you will need the necessary *generalized eigenvectors*.

For your example, the matrix
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}  -1 &  2 &  0 \\  0 &  -1 &  0 \\  0 &  0 &  -2 \end{bmatrix}
$$
we know that $v = (1,0,0)^T$ is an eigenvalue for $-1$ with an eigenvector missing, so we find the associated generalized eigenvector by finding a solution to $(A- \lambda I) x = v$.  So, in this case, we'd solve
$$
\pmatrix{0&2&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&1}x = \pmatrix{1\\0\\0}
$$
which has solution, for example, $x = (0,1/2,0)$.  So, setting
$$
M = \pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&1/2&0\\0&0&1}
$$
We'll find that
$$
J = M^{-1}AM = 
\pmatrix{-1 &  1 &  0 \\  0 &  -1 &  0 \\  0 &  0 &  -2}
$$